# HTML5 Canvas Drag out from browser to desktop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a little image manipulation web app as a project.  I'm trying to implement a Drag canvas image out of the browser to the desktop.  I have done some digging and found

http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout and http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/xgdSC/ (courtesy of TheCssNinja & Brian Grinstead)

```
    function dragoutImages() {

    if (!document.addEventListener) {
        return;
    }

    document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
        var element = e.target;
        var src;

        if (element.tagName === "IMG" && element.src.indexOf("data:") === 0) {
            src = element.src;
        }

        if (element.tagName === "CANVAS") {
            try {
                src = element.toDataURL();
            }
            catch(e) { }
        }

        if (src) {
            var name = element.getAttribute("alt") || "download";
            var mime = src.split(";")[0].split("data:")[1];
            var ext = mime.split("/")[1] || "png";
            var download = mime + ":" + name + "." + ext + ":" + src;

            e.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", download);   
        }
    }, false);
    }


    function drawCanvas(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var lingrad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,150);
    lingrad.addColorStop(0, '#000');
    lingrad.addColorStop(0.5, '#669');
    lingrad.addColorStop(1, '#fff');


    ctx.fillStyle = lingrad;

    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    img.alt = 'downloaded-from-image';

    $(img).appendTo("body");

    }

   dragoutImages();
   drawCanvas();
```

This works for files which are elements of the HTML but I am unable to grab the canvas image and download it using the theory.  Has anyone implemented such a feature?

I have used the canvas.toDataURL to get the image data, if I do an alert I see the encoded image data my canvas drag begins but when outside the browser the icon changes back to the stop symbol.

Looking for approaches and ideas on how to implement this.

This is what I've managed to implement and works pretty well,

```
function download(e){
downloadImageData = eCanv.getImageData(750 - (scaledWidth / 2), 250 - (scaledHeight / 2), scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
dlcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
dlcanvas.setAttribute('width',scaledWidth);
dlcanvas.setAttribute('height',scaledHeight);
dlcontext = dlcanvas.getContext("2d");
dlcontext.putImageData(downloadImageData, 0,0);
url = dlcanvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
//name = document.getElementById("filename").value;
var mime = url.split(";")[0].split("data:")[1];
var name = mime.split("/")[0];
var ext = mime.split("/")[1] || "jpg";
var download = mime + ":" + name + "." + ext + ":" + url;
e.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL", download);        
}
```

Adapted code from cssninja and Brian Grinstead.

Answer (score 0):

No.

For security reasons, Javascript *cannot* write to the local file system.

Javascript can read from the local file system with the filereader:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

It can even write to a sandboxed browser file (localstorage): http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

You could even bounce it off your server and then ask the user if they want to download the image off the server.

Comment: I did understand that was an issue but surely the 2 examples show that it can be done although they are using  different file type than I am looking to use?

Comment: So I *was* able to reproduce Ryan's drag results with Chrome (although on 1 occasion when I abandoned a drop--Chrome froze!) I also got it to work in Firefox.  I couldn't get the drag to work at all on IE.  **However**, when I "dirtied" the canvas with a local asset (I added a local .png to the canvas), none of the dragging worked.  I guess you project would work if you do your imaging without dirtying up the canvas to the point where the browser triggers a security flag.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit buggy.  I managed an implementation that works for me within Chrome but like you found that Chrome froze when a drop was incomplete. I'll put what I did in chrome into the question as an edit. FYI I'm not using the whole canvas I'm selecting a partial image of the canvas and then throwing that to a buffer canvas then using toDataURL to return that canvas data...

Answer (score 0):

For local web based applications you can use or write a local webserver or service and or utilzize for example php to add the functionality to interact with the local filesystem from javascript. Seems this is forgotten that it is not forbidden to install a webserver on the same machine like the browser :)